# "When Adar Comes We Increase in Joy" - already from Adar I?

Tags: calendar, simchah-joy-happiness, adar

Does the Talmudic dictum

> [משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%98_%D7%90) (When Adar comes we increase in joy)

start even in אדר ראשון (Adar I) in a leap year?

Comment: would this mean that Purim Torah should be allowed in Adar I?

Answer (score 14):

Rashi in the linked Gemara says that the reason we are "marbim b'simcha" is because they are "ymei nisim k'mo Purim v'Pesach" based on which some conclude that Adar Rishon is not included, as no miracles happened in that time period.

The Levush (685:1) says that we do not increase simcha in Adar 1.  The Sfas Emes says we do.

Some want to conclude based on the dating of a letter of the Chasam Sofer ([shu"t C.M 20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=792&st=&pgnum=26&hilite=)) that he held we do (the dating says "א׳ דר״ח אדר ראשון שמרבים בו שמחה").

Comment: The Yerushalmi says that Purim happened in a leap year, and thus in Adar Rishon. That would mean that Rashi's concept does not necessarily limit the days of miracles to the second Adar only. For a longer discussion on why then purim is in Adar Sheni see [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/purim/pur63-ml.htm).

Comment: @Yishai thank you for the source.  I don't think that would invalidate those who extrapolate from Rashi (I will try to find where I saw such a thing, no promises) because our _commemoration_ of the miracles is, at the end of the day, in Adar II.

Comment: I agree, but it answers those who go the other way, and find Rashi inconclusive. I don't doubt that it isn't unanimous.

Comment: +1. Can you cite more precisely to the _S'fas Emes_ or _L'vush_?

Comment: @msh210 Cited the levush.  I think the s'fas emes was in chiddushim to Taanis but I don't have a kovetz handy.

Comment: "The Gra and and others maintain that it begins during the first month. Maran Rav Chaim Kanyevsky, shlita agrees with this Shita.

Rav Yaakov Emden, zt'l and others say it begins on the Second month of Adar." (Source: Rabbi Leib Tropper)

Answer (score 5):

[R' Ephraim Greenblatt](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1085&pgNum=285) holds that it applies to some extent to Adar Rishon was well.

[R' Yiztchak Zilberstein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49714&pgnum=75) cites sources for both opinions but concludes somewhat tentatively that Adar I is also included.

The last Lubavitcher Rebbe also holds that Adar I is included. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15833&pgnum=284) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25057&pgNum=71).

See also [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42703&pgNum=158).

Answer (score 3):

The [Shevet Halevi 10:105:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1420&st=&pgnum=91) brings a whole discussion and seemingly  concludes that there is an idea of simcha in the first adar.