# Mishenichnas Adar: only for second month?

Tags: purim, simchah-joy-happiness, chazal, adar, leap-years

In a Jewish leap year like 5784, we have two Adars (Adar I & Adar II). While the famous Memra of Chazal tells us to increase simcha in Adar, this would presumably only apply in the month of which Purim falls out. What about Adar I, is there also a din for Simcha? I've heard its a machloes between the Chasam Sofer and the Rav Yaakov Emden, though I didn't have enough time to look into this. Please bring explicit sources. TY!

Comment: "this would presumably only apply in the month of which Purim falls out" Why do you say this?

Comment: The Rebbe often said that just like in kashrus food can be nullified in 60, so too the 60 days of joy in a leap year have a special power to nullify negativity.

Comment: Unless that's a persons whole existence which would make him a beirya which isn't nullified even in 1000

Comment: Duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35118/when-adar-comes-we-increase-in-joy-already-from-adar-i